# Possible to set dataLabels to display xAxis data instead of yAxis data in HighCharts?

Tags: highcharts

so by reading the documents by default when you enable `dataLabels` on the chart it will render yAxis values, but is it possible to make it render xAxis values?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format labels in Highcharts in two ways:

1. Use [`dataLabels.formatter`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels.formatter) where you have access to `this` (point):

   ```
   formatter: function () {
     return this.x;
   }
   ```

   Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t2cek68m/1/
2. Use [`dataLabels.format`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels.format), where you can put simple template:

   ```
   format: "{x}"
   ```

   Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t2cek68m/

**Note:**

You can use any property from a point, to show this in a label, both `format` and `formatter` can be used:

```
 format: '{point.customValue}'
```

Or:

```
 formatter: function () {
   return this.point.customValue;
 }
```

Where a point is defined as an object:

```
series: [{
  data: [{
    x: 10,
    y: 15,
    customValue: '10x10'
  }]
}]
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t2cek68m/3/

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible just add this code :

```
dataLabels: {
  enabled: true,
  formatter: function() {
    return this.x;
  }
},
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1dmj0f8k/)

Comment: Please people upvote this answer as well, very helpful.